# Android receipt/zigzag drawable/layout

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm in need of creating a receipt layout in Android. 
The idea is very simple, a rectangle layout with a zigzag bottom edge.

The best result would be a drawable/layout with a fixed zigzag size (meaning, fixed half-triangle size), 
which will multiply the amount of triangles according to the shape's actual width, in real time. With a clip maybe,  to have clipped triangles if necessary.

Here is a good example (**edit**: I'm referring to the bottom zigzag line) :

[image]

I actually have no solid idea of how to create it.  Thought of 9 patch,  but it seems unfitting.  Thought of list-layer drawable with horizontal offsets maybe..

Maybe it is possible to create a 9 patch with separate scale sections, to keep the zigzag's aspect ratio... This would also be OK.

**EDIT - ANSWER**
Using @Luksprog 's comment, I easily recreated what I wanted.
Here is some code:

Image (note that height corresponds to the source image size):

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zigzag_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/zigzag" />
```

drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_zigzag"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:antialias="true"
    />
```

Comment: Thx, but you're referring to the list, and I'm referring to the bottom zigzag line...btw thank you for editing!
Actually, maybe it is possible to achieve with an horizontal ListView!:)

Comment: You can't create a nine path for that image. You could simply take one of the zig zag tooth and use it in a bitmap drawable with repeat mode set on it.

Comment: @Luksprog perfect! So simple:P Can you please respond so I can vote your answer? You can use my answer's code if you'd like, it will help others.

Comment: @guy_m i need you help

Comment: @young_08 been a long time but go ahead and ask:) Better to use pm

Comment: by implementing this code it will perfectively work fine but it will show bottom line under ZIGZAG

Please help me to remove this issue
thank you

Comment: Im not sure what happened to you but it should work.  Try being accurate with the height you set,  which should match the resource/drawable height,  or the bottom of it will  strech

Comment: How you done this?

Comment: What do you mean? The answer is located at the bottom of the question. Note that the source image is basically 1 triangle.. Which duplicates horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make a nine path for that image because there is no way to define a stretchable area on either the vertical or horizontal side. To obtain that zig-zag pattern you could extract one of the zig-zag tooth(along with it's background shadow) and wrap it in a `BitmapDrawable` which has the `tileMode` property for repeating the wrapped image inside the drawable bounds. This way the zig-zag tooth will be repeated and you'll compose the pattern.

> note that height corresponds to the source image size

This is a happy scenario, but you could make it work for the case when the height doesn't match. You could for example wrap the zig-zag `BitmapDrawable` in a `LayerDrawable`(along with the actual view drawable(for the rest of the view area)) and then use `setLayerInset()` to place the drawable at the bottom. You could also create your own drawable that places the zig-zag pattern image at the bottom by overriding the onDraw() method.

Comment: Please look at the question... The answer is (edited) there:)

Comment: https://medium.com/android-dev-br/repetir-at%C3%A9-encaixar-390ade3f57bd

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ZigzagView](https://github.com/beigirad/ZigzagView) that is used for this purpose. it supports the zigzag effect for top/bottom/left/right and has a shadow.

add its dependency and make use of it:

```
'com.github.beigirad:ZigzagView:VERSION'
```

```
<ir.beigirad.zigzagview.ZigzagView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    app:zigzagBackgroundColor="#8bc34a"
    app:zigzagElevation="8dp"
    app:zigzagHeight="10dp"
    app:zigzagShadowAlpha="0.9"
    app:zigzagSides="top|bottom|right|left"
    app:zigzagPaddingContent="16dp">
    
    // add child view(s)
    
</ir.beigirad.zigzagview.ZigzagView>
```

[image: preview]

[reference](https://github.com/beigirad/ZigzagView)