# How to achieve zigzag view in middle of cardView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

How can I achieve CardView Something like

[image: this].
If you will see my image carefully you will get to know that this question is not duplicate. I have checked on all given link but they didn't solve my problem. i alredy tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253841/android-zig-zag-layout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761179/android-bottom-zig-zag-shape) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441573/android-receipt-zigzag-drawable-layout) but nothing solved my problem. Please Help me.

I searched every where didn't get any idea. Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @ Nilesh Rathod I got [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253841/android-zig-zag-layout] answer but this didn't work for me.Even I tried this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761179/android-bottom-zig-zag-shape] but of them didn't help.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod can you please Explain So that i can solve my problem.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/26441573/7666442 **EDIT** part

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried again but I didn't get what i'm looking for